# Does being transgender a mental health condition? If no, why not?

Tags: mental-health, sexuality, disorders, gender-sex-identity, gender-specific

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** This question focuses on *scientific aspects* of gender dysphoria only. By no means I desire to disrespect anybody and will gladly have comments about any mistake I might have.

My following question is specifically with the very basic idea of "mental illness" and nothing else --- Why WHO distinguishes between having a common mental illness (e.g. schizophrenia, depression, etc.) and being a transgender person, which by definition referred to people who *** feel or think to*** "have a gender identity that differs from their sex assigned at birth".

Does being transgender a mental health condition? If no, why not?
That is to ask; why in some countries health agencies declassify transgender people as having "mental disorder" (in accordance with the world health organisation (WHO))?
<sub>In other words, what makes being transgender different than being mentally ill?</sub>

Comment: This is like asking if sneezing means having a cold.  Some people are born physically that way, and no amount of psychological treatment can "cure" the condition. But for some people it is a mental condition, like anorexia, a misperception of one's self. Unfortunately politics has entered the situation. Calling it a mental disorder results in protests from people that think this also labels the real transgenders.  Of concern is that these politics are indirectly encouraging the mental cause. [Cliques of transgender girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_onset_gender_dysphoria_controversy)

Comment: *"in accordance with the world health organisation (WHO)"* can you please provide a reference for this claim that the WHO classifies transgenderism a mental health condition?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Read the question again, I said "declassify" not "classify"

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Your question should be: Why would anyone consider transgenderism a mental illness when there's nothing about transgenderism that meets the definition of illness?

Comment: @CareyGregory It's not a wrong question. But I understand your point :)

Comment: @CareyGregory I generally agree with you, besides in cases of permanent detransition ; I have listened to tens upon tens (if not a few hundreds) stories of detransitioners of various countries, ages and sub-cultures ; their stories were almost always very saddening and depressing but most of all, in my opinion, show that the picture is more complicated than traditionally thought ; that there might be **non general / extra ordinary / extremely rare** in which a mental problem or illness could bring someone to imagine a gender dysphoria and do transsexualism and then totally regret it.

Comment: and then totally regret it - as I have explained in depth in my answer; I emphasis here as I emphasized in my answer and in comments that these stories and motivations are etiologically very different and obviously statistically radically different then those of transsexuals who will never regret their change and passionately protest the illegitimate usage of detransition cases to mock the transgender community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transgender is a very broad and not a very well defined term, but a much more well defined term for which people most often mean is *feeling a persistent, consistent and insistent need for [transsexualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transsexual) since early as memory appeared in mind* (most often referred to as [gender dysphoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_dysphoria)) which as of itself is not a mental illness and generally isn't caused by a mental illness as I will further explain:

Gender dysphoria can be caused by various [intersexualism conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex) by which a human is somewhere between a female and a male at least by *brain anatomy and physiology* and of course, that effects [developmental psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_psychology) in the course of life (hence feeling, in a sense, somewhere between a female-woman and a male-man) but with a case-dependent *proper treatment*, if at all needed, a person can live functioning, constructing and possibly very happy life and do lots of good in this world.

Further, gender dysphoria is a "mental condition" in the senses that:

- It requires tremendous amounts of time and energy to figure out how to deal with the dissonance between *gender sensation* or *[gender identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity)* and body appearance
- *It requires tremendous amounts of time and energy to* chose how to deal with it and doing so in practice, which as of 2020 is going through a most likely (yet not necessary) vast change in body appearance, apparel, cosmetics, bureaucracy and so forth including taking hormonal treatment (and for some trans persons - different types of surgery)
- This is probably hardest (no pun intended): It requires dealing with ignorance and [transphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transphobia) and often suffer from drug abuse, harsh violence and so forth (with many transgenders being, sadly, sexually abused, murdered or got suicide)

**That said;**

It should be noted that indeed there are some **non general / extra ordinary / extremely rare** cases in which some mental illness cause someone (as part of a *delusional* or *dissociative* phase) a gender dysphoria so she or he might actually transition based on wrong diagnosis in the end but these sad cases (which are barely seriously researched) will most likely end in [detransition (permanent type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detransition) and are different than generally all cases of transsexualism in **etiology**.
Yet, these rare cases should be taken very seriously as people lost body parts and/or functions (such as gonads, genitals and female breast or hair or got a way softer voice and so forth) `or` got extra body parts and/or functions (such as female breast or more permanent hair or deeper voice and so forth) for which they are probably regret to this day.
I note that these `should-end-in-permanent-detransition` cases are neither the majority, nor the most of cases of gender dysphoria, per what I understand and explained.

---

Update (comment notes that might get deleted):

<sub>One has to differentiate between a *mental state* (or "condition"), a *mental disorder* (not being in order with the common mentality which isn't necessarily bad) and a *mental illness* (which at least harms or by proper consistent evidence, can consistently harm others and/or a person itself seriously);
 As I have explained, transsexualism is a technical process that surly isn't a mental illness or disorder and gender dysphoria that usually cause it, generally isn't caused by a mental illness or disorder.</sub>

<sub>By my opinion, supporting both those who really need transsexualism and the tiny minority of detransitioners (permanent or not) and finding ways to prevent the extremely rare cases of `should-end-in-detransition` transsexualism (especially permanent type) is one way to make this world better.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**Being transgendered is NOT a mental health condition**.

The American Psychiatric Association states that a mental health disorder requires distress or disability ([APA, n.d.](https://www.apa.org/topics/lgbt/transgender)).

> A psychological state is considered a mental disorder only if it causes significant distress or disability. Many transgender people do not experience their gender as distressing or disabling, which implies that identifying as transgender does not constitute a mental disorder.

The WHO classified transgenderism as being a *gender identity disorder* in ICD-10 under the section entitled *mental and behavioural disorders*. However, in the latest version of the ICD, ([ICD-11](http://www.who.int/classifications/icd/en/)), gender incongruence is defined as **a marked and persistent incongruence** between a person's experienced gender and assigned sex and is under the section entitled *sexual health*.

Dr. Lale Say, a reproductive health expert at the World Health Organization, said:

> It was taken out from mental health disorders because we had a better understanding that this was not actually a mental health condition ([Say, 2018](https://youtu.be/kyCgz0z05Ik)), and leaving it there was causing stigma.

#### References

APA, (n.d.). *Answers to Your Questions & About transgender people, gender identity, and gender expression* Retrieved from: https://www.apa.org/topics/lgbt/transgender

Say, (2018) *WHO: Revision of ICD-11 (gender incongruence/transgender) — questions and answers (Q&A) Rterieved from: https://youtu.be/kyCgz0z05Ik

Comment: Thanks, @Chris for the answer. So based on WHO, it is considered as a "gender identity disorder" which means it is a disorder (according to WHO), right? If so, shouldn't a "disorder" be "cured", if possible? How different it is from other types of mental disorders? I believe many transgenders do experience several types of distressing in their lives, especially when they see a gap between their body and their self-view.

Comment: @linker - Read my answer again. The WHO **used** to call it a gender identity disorder, **but no longer does**.

Comment: Why is that? Why transgenderism is classified different than mental disorders? I need to know the scientific reasoning behind it.

Comment: @linker The care that leads to best outcomes for people experiencing gender incongruence is affirmation care, which can include acceptance of gender identity from a social/psychological perspective as well as medical interventions like hormonal treatments and sometimes surgery. So, for some people it seems like treating their *body* as "wrong" makes more sense, while others in supportive circumstances may identify as transgender without any substantial distress such that intervention is unnecessary.

Comment: See also https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/18778/14382 https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19795/14382